# How can I restrict my method arguments for only Set and List type of collection, not Map?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have similar kind of two methods for different types of arguments.  
**1.** For `java.util.Set`

```
public static <T> List<? super T> consumeSet(Set<? extends T> collection){
    return null;
}
```

**2.** For `java.util.List` BR>

```
public static <T> List<? super T> consumeList(List<? extends T> collection){
    return null;
}
```

I want to implement one common method which consumes only implements of `List` or `Set` but not `Map`. I am trying below mentioned method signature. Is it the right way to do this? If not, can anyone suggest me the right way? Thanks.

```
public static <T,V extends Set<T> & List<T>> List<? super T> consumeListAndSetButNotMap(V collection){
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: why don't you overload the method 1 which take List and 2nd which take Set as an argument

Comment: question is not about finding alternatives of the requirement, but question is about how to do it with using `Generics` in one method signature? is it not possible ?

Comment: Note that `V extends Set<T> & List<T>` means `V` must implement _both_ `Set<T>` and `List<T>`.  Except for an immutable empty list-set, this is not possible to do while respecting the contracts of `List.equals` and `Set.equals`.

Comment: Yes, you are right @JeffreyBosboom, that is what I was just trying..! but I was not succeed. So was looking for right way :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the shared `Collection` interface. That won't accept `Map`.

Comment: Thanks @Sezin, that is one of the solution. But what if I want to implement it using one method signature? Is it not possible?

Comment: You mean explicitly setting something like this as argument?

method(? extends List && ? extends Set)

AFAIK you can't do it in Java. Overloading is an option as amit bhardwaj said.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia i think @Sezin is right here either you use `Collection` or overload the method . But keep trying if you get anything please do share with us.